# VBA Macro array file naming query

Tags: vba, ms-word

A colleague is preparing a mail merge in word, there are 7 addressees, I have the following code to print each page to pdf and save it as a pdf named uniquely from an array. The array only seems to allow so many file names though, if the array code goes onto two lines it seems to throw a wobbly.I am pretty new to all of this so please be nice haha! I have attached the code below:
Sub SplitIntoSeparatePDFs()

```
Dim oDocMultiple As Document
Dim oDocSingle As Document
Dim oRngPage As Range
Dim iCurrentPage As Long, iPageCount As Long
Dim strNewFileName As Variant
Dim arrFileNames() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' path to original (long) document
Set oDocMultiple = Documents.Open("C:\Users\lwal4\Desktop\Word Version of OP res care mail merge.docx")
'instantiate the range object
Set oRngPage = oDocMultiple.Range
' put all file names in an array
arrFileNames = Array("adl plc.pdf", "advent estates limited.pdf", "albemarle rest home ltd.pdf""avery homes (nelson) limited.pdf", "avery homes nuneaton limited.pdf", "b and e thorpe-smith.pdf", "barchester healthcare homes ltd.pdf", "ben - motor & allied trades benevolent fund.pdf", "bentley house limited.pdf", "benvarden residential care homes limited.pdf", "berkley care (warwick) limited.pdf", "bm care warwick limited.pdf", "bupa care homes (ans) limited.pdf", "butts croft limited.pdf", "care uk community partnerships ltd.pdf", "caring homes healthcare group limited.pdf", "central england healthcare limited.pdf", "clarendon manor limited.pdf", , "coate water care company (church viewnursing home) limited.pdf", "cow lees care home ltd.pdf", "craighaven limited.pdf", "crosscrown ltd.pdf", "culpeper care limited.pdf",
```

"adl plc.pdf", "advent estates limited.pdf", "albemarle rest home ltd.pdf""avery homes (nelson) limited.pdf", "avery homes nuneaton limited.pdf", "b and e thorpe-smith.pdf", "barchester healthcare homes ltd.pdf", "ben - motor & allied trades benevolent fund.pdf", "bentley house limited.pdf", "benvarden residential care homes limited.pdf", "berkley care (warwick) limited.pdf", "bm care warwick limited.pdf", "bupa care homes (ans) limited.pdf", "butts croft limited.pdf", "care uk community partnerships ltd.pdf", "caring homes healthcare group limited.pdf", "central england healthcare limited.pdf", "clarendon manor limited.pdf", , "coate water care company (church viewnursing home) limited.pdf", "cow lees care home ltd.pdf", "craighaven limited.pdf", "crosscrown ltd.pdf", "culpeper care limited.pdf")

```
iCurrentPage = 1
'get the original document's page count
iPageCount = oDocMultiple.Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)

Do Until iCurrentPage > iPageCount
    If iCurrentPage = iPageCount Then
        'last page (there won't be a next page)
        oRngPage.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
    Else
        'Find the beginning of the next page
        'Must use the Selection object. The Range.Goto method will not work on a page
        Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, iCurrentPage + 1
        'Set the end of the range to the point between the pages
        oRngPage.End = Selection.Start
    End If

    'copy the page into the Windows clipboard
    oRngPage.Copy

    'create a new document
    Set oDocSingle = Documents.Add

    'paste the clipboard contents to the new document
    oDocSingle.Range.Paste

    'remove any manual page break to prevent a second blank
    oDocSingle.Range.Find.Execute Findtext:="^m", ReplaceWith:=""

    'build a new file name based on the original multi-paged path and name from the array
    strNewFileName = oDocMultiple.Path & "\" & arrFileNames(i)


    Debug.Print strNewFileName

    'save the new single-paged document
    oDocSingle.SaveAs FileName:=strNewFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False

    'move to the next document (1 pages later)
    iCurrentPage = iCurrentPage + 1

    'close the new document without saving
    oDocSingle.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    'go to the next page
    oRngPage.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: What does this mean, exactly: ` if the array code goes onto two lines`? Your code is not formatted correctly in the question, please use the [edit] link below the question to make sure it displays correctly, then perhaps we could see what is meant... Four preceding spaces, minimum, is required for content to be formatted as code. Please also describe exactly what is meant by "wobbly" - that doesn't tell us anything. Are you getting an error message? If yes, what is it? Which line of code is triggering it?

Comment: Evidently, you're trying to split the merge output into separate PDFs post- merge. If your data source has the required names in one of the fields, you'd do far better to create the separate files as part of the merge itself. For code to do that, see *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. Alternatively, if the names are present in a particular paragraph in the mailmerge output, you could use the code from the *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* topic there.